# Add text to text document via automator

Tags: macos, shell, automation, applescript, automator

I automated a lot of my tasks to save time with help of Hazel or Automator.

However I am super stuck right now with a simple problem: I can't figure out how to add text to an existing text document via Automator.

So far I tried to figure this out with various shell / apple scripts that I adapted from sources from here or other forums. – None of them were working so far, that's why I am hoping to get some help here.

Specifically this would be the ideal solution:

1. Automator copies an existing text template to a pre-defined location.
2. I am prompted to insert/paste some text into a field.
3. Automator pastes this text on top of the text file that just has been copied to the new location.

Everything worked so far except the third step.

Here's the automator workflow. I disabled the Apple Scripts down there,  because they were just copy-pasted from other forums and not working.
[My Automator workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOodj.png)

Thanks so much. Looking forward to hearing your ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably a handful of ways to approach this but here is one that is relatively straightforward and depends upon neither applescript nor variables. It does require a destination folder ahead of time (which is where your template will be copied to).

- Get Specified Finder Items (from folder A, i.e. folder containing your original template)
- Get Folder Contents
- Filter Finder Items
- Copy Finder Items (to folder B, i.e. destination folder, check Replacing…)
- Open Finder Items (Open with: TextEdit — opens copied template document — this will become the finished document)
- Store Disk Item References (store copied template file reference)
- Ask for Text (while testing, I used 'get specified text' instead but I guess that's irrelevant now)
- New Text File (contents are your promo blurb)
- Retrieve Disk Item References (gets promo blurb file reference AND copied template file reference)
- Combine Text Files (prepends promo blurb to template text)
- Set Contents of Textedit Document (By: Replacing — Replaces copied template document's text with new combined text)
- Retrieve Disk Item References (gets file reference of updated copied template)
- Rename Finder Items: Name Single Item (to whatever)
- Quit Application (TextEdit, check Ask to save changes)

In essence, the workflow puts the text from your template and your promo blurb into textedit documents and grabs each text and substitutes the combined text. When the workflow completes its run, you should have a text file containing both texts with the promo blurb at the top. If you would like to choose where to save the text file, remove the last three actions and you will be left with the open TextEdit document containing the combined text.

Comment: This is gold man, thank you so much. It worked for me, but I'd like to add for other people having the same issue, that you need Third Party Automations (Store Disk Item References and Retrieve Disk Item Reference aren't included within the Automator. I got the automations from here: http://automator.us/downloads.html)

Only one issue occurred to me: When quitting the text file I get prompted this "You don’t have permission to write to the folder that the file “Test” is in." – Is there any way to pass this prompt within the automator? – Still the solution is so worthy, I am super happy!

Comment: I forgot about having to add those actions. This is the first time I've actually used them. FWIW, Apple did create them. I would speculate that they made them a separate download to provide examples for other vendors but who knows. As to the permission prompt, I don't get that (I'm using Sierra if that makes a difference). Maybe try adding Automator under System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Accessibility where it would allow Automator to control the computer. Glad it helped but let me know if the above fixes the prompt.

Comment: Interesting. And thanks for the quick response! – Putting Automator to Accessibility (and further to 'Full Disc Access' did not solve the problem. But I can click on "cancel" in TextEdit and then save the file manually. MacOS got a lot of extra security since Mojave I think, which makes it hard to figure out where the problem comes from.

Comment: Until you can figure out that last bit, remove the 'quit application' action. It's really only there to force a save (and give the script… closure). That way you won't need to cancel manually. Note that if you have saved the workflow as an app, it is that new app which requires the security access (not Automator). You're right about the security challenges with each new release. Sierra was a simpler world.

Comment: I just did, thanks a lot, Mockman, you're the best.